# Finding a value in an array of arrays in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, formula

I'm trying to indicate if an ID from one table is listed in another, using the following formula I almost get what I want except I get false negatives when an item in Table1 has multiple links listed. I thought FIND might help but can't work it out.

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH([@ID],Table1[LINKS],0)))
```

**Table1**

| ID | LINKS |
| --- | --- |
| 01 |  |
| 02 | 01 |
| 03 | 01 \n 02 |
| 04 | 03 |

**Table2**

| ID | LINKED |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | TRUE |
| 02 | FALSE |
| 03 | TRUE |
| 04 | FALSE |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughtprocess about `FIND()` is right. You can try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" \n "&[@ID]&" \n "," \n "&Table1[LINKS]&" \n ")))>0
```

And if `\n` is a placeholder for a newline, just replace these literals with `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: Thank you.  In the end I got away with: =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND([@ID], Table1[LINKS])))>0

Comment: @DanielAshby. Great, but don't forget that this might give false positives at some point.

Comment: Thanks I've updated the IDs to be in the format ’XXX-0000 which should stop any overlap if I have more than 10000 entries I'll consider expansion of the placeholder values